# Ubuntu 20.04 no longer wakes monitors from sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I'm running kernel 5.4.0.58. Since booting into this kernel after updating, something changed such that the system sleeps (or something) after an unknown period of idle time, and refuses to wake. It stops sending signal to the monitors, but keeps power to the keyboard, and it transitions to this state only when I'm away and can't see it happen. When I get back, using the keyboard or mouse does not wake it up. My only choice is to restart the machine.

Before this update, I had the machine configured to never sleep automatically. Now I don't know what setting is making it do this. In the Power settings, I have chosen "Blank Screen: Never" and "Automatic Suspend: Off", but those settings must not be controlling this behavior.

How can I even start debugging this problem? Are there any logs that might tell me what was happening before the last abrupt shutdown? Does this problem sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might point to a problem? This is generally the first place to check for system-wide issues.

Comment: The log is full of messages from when I was asleep, so it must not be sleeping, but just turning the monitors off and refusing to wake them. Nothing really sticks out to me to explain why.

Comment: I just installed the latest driver (nvidia-driver-455) for my video card (GTX 980). The system update could explain the removal of the previously installed Nvidia driver; one remnant package was left behind (libnvidia-compute-435) as evidence. This might fix the issue. Time will tell.

Comment: I've had to reinstall nVidia drivers after major upgrades.